# tuplex.count(1) return 3 for the tuplex = ('abc', 1, True, 'abc', 23, 1)

Tags: python, tuples

```
tuplex = ('abc', 1, True, 'abc', 23, 1) -
tuplex.count(1)
```

Returns `3` despite of there are only two number `1` in the tuple. Could you please explain?

Comment: `True == 1` in Python.

Comment: oh well, thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

docs for python3 says:

Booleans: These represent the truth values False and True [...] Boolean values behave like the values 0 and 1, respectively, in almost all contexts, the exception being that when converted to a string, the strings "False" or "True" are returned, respectively.

Comment: always paste the reference source!